# AMP HTML page/URL naming

Tags: amp-html

The (canonical) URLs of my website look like

- https://example.com/foo.html (English page) and
- https://example.com/es/foo.html (Spanish page).

I want to add AMP HTML versions. Is it a good idea to name the AMP versions like this? Are there other/better options?

- https://example.com/foo.amp.html (English page) and
- https://example.com/es/foo.amp.html (Spanish page).

(I saw this pattern on [ampbyexample](https://ampbyexample.com/introduction/how_to_publish_amps/) without explanation.)

Answer (score 3):

I dont see why you should have a problem. The point of canonical URL and AMP URL was about [Making Your Page Discoverable](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery) where you link AMP-pages to its non-AMP pages version (because [Google will now favor AMPified pages](https://www.wired.com/2016/02/google-will-now-favor-pages-use-fast-loading-tech/)):

**Linking pages with < link >**

In order to solve this problem, we add information about the AMP page to the non-AMP page and vice versa, in the form of  tags in the .

Add the following to the non-AMP page:

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp/document.html">
```

And this to the AMP page:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/full/document.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

Aslong as you have the canonicals from the non-AMP version to the AMP version of the page I don't think it matters.

Personally I go for `www.example.com/amp/foo.html`

Answer (score 0):

We use a query parameter to tell the application what to display, which also works:

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/document.html?layout=amp">
```